# Deleting docker volumes on Dokku

Tags: docker, dokku

How do I delete volumes in a Dokku app so I can push changes to those folders again via git deploy?

I tried running this:

```
dokku docker-options:remove app build, deploy, run "-v /opt/app/folder:/app/folder"
```

This does not change anything though.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with help from the very friendly guys over at the Dokku github repo.

I had to remove the spaces between the phases:

```
dokku docker-options:remove app build,deploy,run "-v /opt/app/folder:/app/folder"
```